# Test series for convergance

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling with this series:

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{e^n\left ( \left ( n-1! \right ) \right )^2}{\left ( 2n + 1 \right )!}$$

I've tried testing it with a ratio test. As follows:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{{n+1}}}{a_{n}}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n+1} \cdot \left ( n! \right )^2}{\left ( 2n+3 \right )!}\cdot \frac{\left ( 2n+1 \right )!}{e^n \left ( n-1 \right )!}$$

And in the end, I'm getting:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n+1} \cdot n^2 \cdot \left ( n-1 \right )!}{e^n \left ( 2n+2 \right )\left ( 2n+3 \right )}$$

And this limit is positive infinity so series diverge, but in the Wolfram Alpha I'm getting the opposite result.

No idea if I'm wrong or the wolfram is wrong. So I will be happy for any help.

Comment: (n-1)! should be squared in your expression for $1/a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go back to your initial result for the ratio test, since there's more that can be done there, but with a correction: the $(n-1)!$ term should be squared, and we'll have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n+1} \cdot \left ( n! \right )^2}{\left ( 2n+3 \right )!}\cdot \frac{\left ( 2n+1 \right )!}{e^n \left (( n-1 \right )!)^2}$$

We can do the following:

- $e^{n+1}/e^n = e$
- $n!/(n-1)! = n$, and thus their squares simplify to $n^2$
- $(2n+1)!/(2n+3)! = 1/((2n+2)(2n+3))$

Ergo,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{n+1} \cdot \left ( n! \right )^2}{\left ( 2n+3 \right )!}\cdot \frac{\left ( 2n+1 \right )!}{e^n \left (( n-1 \right )!)^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e \cdot n^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$$

The denominator simplifies to have $4n^2$ plus a linear and a constant term. In the infinite limit, the $n^2$ dominates and thus

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e \cdot n^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{e \cdot n^2}{4n^2} = \frac e 4 \approx 0.68$$

Since this value is less than $1$, it gives us convergence by the ratio test, which agrees with Wolfram's result.

Comment: +1..... More simply, when $n>0$ we have $0<en^2/[(2n+2)(2n+3)]<en^2/4n^2=e/4<0.7$ which is  enough info for the Ratio Test.